# I am trying to make an AI program in python with random module

Tags: python, random, append, artificial-intelligence

I have been learning to make AI in python. I used the random module and the append command to give unknown input values. this is my code:

```
import random
greetings=["Hi there!","Sup!"]
goodbye=["have a nice day","byee!"]
keywords=["maths","swimming"]
responses=["one of the most interesting subjects","The best sport in the world"]
print(random.choice(greetings))
user=input("Chat with me(type 'bye' to quit) -> ")
user=user.lower()
keyword_found=False
while(user!="bye"):
    
    for i in range(len(keywords)):
        if(keywords[i] in user):
            print("Bot: "+responses[i])
            keyword_found==True
    if(keyword_found==False):
        new_keyword=input("Couldn't get ya. pls tell me the name of the topic which you are talking about : ")
        keywords.append(new_keyword)
        new_response=input("Pls tell me about it : ")
        responses.append(new_response)
    user=input("Chat with me(type 'bye' to quit) -> ")
    user=user.lower()
```

The program is working fine with known inputs. But when i am using the append, the "Couldn't get ya" is popping up even after appending the new input. See the attached picture to understand the scenario.

Please help me to fix it. I would be really greatful

[This is the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqtM9.png)

Comment: `keyword_found==True` checks if the variable is `True`, it doesn't set its value. To set its value, do `keyword_found=True`

Answer (score 0):

Error in code at line 15 `keyword_found==True`, where you are not assigning variable but rather checking if True

Working code with minimum modifications:

```py
import random
greetings=["Hi there!","Sup!"]
goodbye=["have a nice day","byee!"]
keywords=["maths","swimming"]
responses=["one of the most interesting subjects","The best sport in the world"]
print(random.choice(greetings))

user=input("Chat with me(type 'bye' to quit) -> ")
user=user.lower()
keyword_found=False

while(user!="bye"):
    for i, keyword in enumerate(keywords):
        if keyword in user:
            print("Bot: "+responses[i])
            keyword_found=True
            break
            
    if not keyword_found:
        new_keyword=input("Couldn't get ya. pls tell me the name of the topic which you are talking about : ")
        keywords.append(new_keyword)
        new_response=input("Pls tell me about it : ")
        responses.append(new_response)
        
    user=input("Chat with me(type 'bye' to quit) -> ")
    user=user.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Made 3 changes (commented lines with # 1 2 3) and it should work fine:

```
for i in range(len(keywords)):
    if (keywords[i] in user):
        print("Bot: " + responses[i])
        keyword_found = True # 1
        break # 2
if (keyword_found == False):
    new_keyword = input("Couldn't get ya. pls tell me the name of the topic which you are talking about : ")
    keywords.append(new_keyword)
    new_response = input("Pls tell me about it : ")
    responses.append(new_response)
keyword_found = False # 3
user = input("Chat with me(type 'bye' to quit) -> ")
user = user.lower()
```

Comment: ...what are the 3 changes? We shouldn't have to mentally `diff` questions and answers to understand them. Please read [answer].

Comment: I wrote comments # 1 2 3 in the code. Maybe should've mentioned that more explicitly.

Comment: Okay, and why are these changes important? Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Again, please read [answer].